# Django проблема с кешем

Tags: django

Настроил по мануалам систему кеширования в Django, но при попытке занести значение в кеш, выбивает ошибку. Облазил все доп.ресурсы но не нашел решения, и даже не понятно в какую сторону "копать". Просьба помочь

Настройки в settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    'default':{
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'MAX_ENTRIES':3000
        }
    }
}

CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = "my_cache_alias"



MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

(Как пример)
views.py:

```
from django.core.cache import cache, caches
x = cache.set('asd', 'Hello')
```

Код ошибки:

```
Django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: Вы в views.py обращаетесь к кэшу прямо так не внутри функции? Естественно так нельзя, ведь на момент загрузки views.py настройки кэша ещё не загрузились

Comment: Работает, спасибо) А можно ли занести значение в кеш к примеру test.py и "выплюнуть" это значение в forms.py ?